# Understanding "compound subtraction assignment" in Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am busy learning Javascript programming for college. As I am new to javascript ,I  need some clarity on a function a the book has given me to work on please.

The below is a simple calculation in JS to multiply a user input value by 100 and then multiple it on another input value.

```
function calcStaff() {
"use strict";
var num = document.getElementById("photognum");
var hrs = document.getElementById("photoghrs");
totalCost -= photographerCost;
photographerCost = num.value * 100 * hrs.value;
totalCost += photographerCost;
document.getElementById("estimate").innerHTML = "$" + totalCost;
```

}

The code works fine and everything run perfect. However I do not understand why we need the following code "totalCost -= photographerCost;"

When I comment this line out it does mess up the calculation , but I dont understand why.

Could someone please explain this Assignment Operator.

Kind Regards

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Subtraction_assignment)

Answer (score 0):

Unless `totalCost` and `photographerCost` are set prior to that line within the context that the function is in, it is completely unnecessary. In fact, especially with the `"use strict"`, if there is no other relevant code, then I am surprised that it is not breaking the code.

So actually by that logic those values must be set elsewhere in the code.  They're probably set at a global level so that they can be used in other calculations.  So that line of code is removing the old `photographerCost` from the `totalCost` before calculating and adding in the new `photographerCost`.